# How to Fix: My Web App forces all users to "interact" with the same list, instead of giving each user their own list

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

After hours of desperately googling, I ask for anyone that could possibly help. I have created a web application where the user can add guests to a list, but when I launched the app to the web, everytime a guest was added to the list by one user, the list would update the entire website and everyone could see, no matter what device you checked it on instead of simply updating the list on the users device/session only. It seems to be forcing everyone into one shared list. I built the application using spring boot and had the objects added to the HttpSession, then switched them to simple ModelAttributes to maybe fix the bug, but nothing. I hope this makes sense and someone else has dealt with this before.

My Guest Service class was designed with all static methods and has the static instance ArrayList holding all of the guests added. I thought me designing the class to be static caused all of the users to be forced into the same list, so I redesigned it to not be static and Autowired the class wherever necessary, but that didn't do the trick, so I am asking for help, desperately.

I could post code, but I have no idea what could be causing this bug and did not want to simply copy and paste my entire Web Application. GitHub Link: https://github.com/JavaJonathan/PortfolioWebsite

My goal is for every user to be able to work on their Guest List instead of everyone sharing the same Guest List.

Comment: Unless you're lucky enough to connect with an SO user who finds your paricular case familiar it will be awfully hard to help you without narrowing it down and posting some code.  If there's too much of your application to post, consider building [a smaller, simpler example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) that also replicates your problem.  This might even reveal some aspects of your problem to you―but if not at least you'll have code to discuss in seeking help.

Comment: I would post code, its just I don't want you all to have to go through hundreds of lines of code (Simple Beans, HTML Pages, Service Classes, etc.) I figured if I conveyed the issue well enough someone could help. Your advice to rebuild a smaller version that does essentially the same thing was good advice, but the bug cannot be found until it is launched to the web, so that will have to be a final option. Maybe if you/anyone simply saw the software, you'd understand the issue? (javajonathan.com/GuestListTitlePage) If not I will likely have to recreate the issue and launch a smaller app

Comment: If your code is too big consider providing a github link, so that we may be of help.Abstract questions are harder to answer and root cause is harder to pinpoint.

Comment: Good idea, the GitHub Link is https://github.com/JavaJonathan/PortfolioWebsite

Comment: Have a look at this article which explains bean scope. [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes) From your explanation it sounds like there is a component with a singleton or application scope which should instead have a session scope.

Answer (score 0):

@NicoE Your response led me to the answer, I tried to annotate the Service class with session scope, but then I started to receive NullPointerExceptions, so after a few frustrating hours, I found another stack overflow post explaining: "So where should @Scope go?

Annotating @Controller with @Scope("session") won't help as it will create session scoped controllers but the service they have injected is still a singleton.

Annotating only Service bean won't work either, cause @Controller is a singleton and it's dependencies are autowired on application startup.

Annotating both @Service and @Controller might work, but seems a bit heavy handed." Out of all of the tutorials I've watched, none of them explained bean scopes. Thank you for saving me from many more frustrating programming hours.